# How can I update data within Detail table and don't loose range selection and filters?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have latest enterprise React agGrid table with Master/Detail grid. My data is fetched on the client every 5 seconds and then put immutably to the redux store. React grid component is using `deltaRowDataMode={true}` props and `deltaRowDataMode: true` in Detail options.

My master grid performs normally as expected: if I have range selected, grid would keep selection after the data updates, so would filters and visibility menu would be still opened. But Detail grid behaves differently: on data refresh selections are being removed, visibility menu closes and grid jumps if filters were changed.

I've read in docs that when I open Detail grid it's being created from scratch, but in my case I don't close Detail. Anywhere I've tried `keepDetailRows=true` flag, which solved problems with jumping on update and selection loss, but Detail grid doesn't update data now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are only two possible options according to the docs https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail/#changing-data-refresh. The first one is a detail table redraws everytime a data in a master row changes and the second one is a detail row doesn't changes at all if a flag suppressRefresh is enabled. Strange decision, awful beahviour...

Update.

Hello again. I found a coupe of solutions.

The first one is to use a `detailCellRendererParams` in table's options and set suppressRefresh to `true`. It gives an opportunity to use `getDetailGridInfo` to get detail-table's `api`.
While the detail-table's refreshing is disabled, using `detailGridInfo` allows to set a new `data` to a detail-table.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const api = gridApiRef;
    api && api.forEachNode(node => {
      const { detailNode, expanded } = node;
      if (detailNode && expanded) {
        const detailGridInfo = api.getDetailGridInfo(detailNode.id);
        const rowData = detailNode.data.someData; // your nested data

        if (detailGridInfo) {
          detailGridInfo.api.setRowData(rowData);
        }
      }
    });
}, [results]);
```

The second one is to use a custom `cellRenderer`, wicth is much more flexible and allows to use any content inside a cellRenderer.
In table's options set `detailCellRenderer`: 'yourCustomCellRendereForDetailTable.
In yourCustomCellRendereForDetailTable you can use

```
this.state = {
    rowData: [],
}
```

Every cellRenderer has a refresh metod which can be used as follow.

```
  refresh(params) {
    const newData = [ ...params.data.yourSomeData];
    const oldData = this.state.rowData;

    if (newData.length !== oldData.length) {
      this.setState({
        rowData: newData,
      });
    }

    if (newData.length === oldData.length) {
      if (newData.some((elem, index) => {
        return !isEqual(elem, oldData[index]);
      })) {
        this.setState({
          rowData: newData,
        });
      }
   }

    return true;
  }
```

Using method `refresh` this way gives a fully customizable approach of using a `detailCellRenderer`.

Note. To get a better performance with using an immutable data like a redux it needs to set `immutableData` to `true` in both main and detail tables.